# Recording the execution path of a C# program?

Tags: c#, trace

I'm looking for a way to record the execution path of a program (i.e. the branches the program/method takes in a particular execution) into a file. I need this piece of information to know what path my inputs take and make performance-related decisions.

[Prof-It](http://dotnet.jku.at/projects/prof-it/) for C# looked very promising, but unfortunately it doesn't support the newest versions of Visual Studio.

My current plan is to generate a unique ID at every branch in the program, and during the execution, I record that id. However, this seems to be a very time-consuming process.

Comment: What you are looking for is called a profiler.  There are several .Net profilers available, included on in some editions of Visual Studio.  That's what you should be searching for.  Note that questions about recommending a specific tool/utility are off-topic.

Comment: While question is likely too broad for SO you may find following blog useful if you decide to implement profiler yourself [CLR Profiling API Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davbr/).

Answer (score 1):

Smth like

```
Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
```

or

```
System.Diagnostics.StackFrame
```

?